# MVC @HTML.Action in if statement causing issues

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am working on a combined EDIT / New item page and want to check a list for items and then call `HTML.Action()` on a default value if `.Count > 0` or loop through the list calling the same `HTML.Action()` to return the same partial view with different data.

Code so far that is not working:

```
@{ 
    var list = @Model.MyList.FindAll(x=>x.somval == someotherval);

    if (list.Count == 0)
    {
        @Html.Action("MyFunc", "MyController", new { MyData = Default.Value });
    }
    else
    {
        foreach(var Item in @Model.MyList)
        {
            @Html.Action("MyFunc", "MyController", new { MyData = Item.Data });
        }
    }
}
```

The issue is that the closing `}` for the first `@Html.Action()` is causing a compile error (expected ',').  There has to be something simple that i am missing but I cannot seem to find the issue through googling.

EDIT Added full code.

EDIT: Thanks to Ashley Medway answer (posted before I edited to include the full code)  I now have the following that is working

```
@{var list = @Model.MyList.FindAll(x=>x.somval == someotherval); }

@if (list.Count == 0)
{
    Html.Action("MyFunc", "MyController", new { MyData = Default.Value });
}
else
{
    foreach(var Item in list)
    {
        Html.Action("MyFunc", "MyController", new { MyData = Item.Data });
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: IIRC you shouldn't need the preceding `@`s if you're already in code mode. If you're within the page, only the if should start with an @, e.g. `@if (Model.Bool == true)`.

Comment: Can you show complete view relevant code?

Comment: you shouldn't need the semicolons at the end of the actionlinks... still thinking about the rest of the problem

Comment: To be honest that view looks correct, other than as I mentioned before the semicolons. What is the viewmodel you are using? When the error occurs is the list populated or empty? How is the list populated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code that I would expect to work would look like this:

```
@if (Model.MyList.Count == 0)
{
    @Html.Action("MyFunc", "MyController", new { MyData = Default.Value })
}
else
{
    foreach(var Item in Model.MyList)
    {
        @Html.Action("MyFunc", "MyController", new { MyData = Item.Data })
    }
}
```

**FIX 1**
An `if` statement in a razor view needs to start with an `@`, assuming that the if statement is not wrapped an another code block.

Change `if (Model.MyList.Count == 0)` to `@if (Model.MyList.Count == 0)`

**FIX 2**
Remove `@` from inside the `foreach` loop. As we are already inside a code block we do not need the `@` to access the model.

Change `foreach(var Item in @Model.MyList)` to `foreach(var Item in Model.MyList)`

**FIX 3**
Removing `;` from the end of `@Html.Action(...)`. Semicolons are not needed to terminate a line in the razor view. *When using HTML helpers, it would still be needed in a some scenarios but the compiler will let you know :)*

Leaving the semicolon `;` in will not actually break your view but it will result in semicolons being added to your rendered HTML.

Answer (score 5):

You need to **use @ before if statment** and **remove @ before foreach**.

```
@if (Model.MyList.Count == 0)
{
    @Html.Action("MyFunc", "MyController", new { MyData = Default.Value })
}
else
{
    foreach (var Item in Model.MyList)
    {
        @Html.Action("MyFunc", "MyController", new { MyData = Item.Data })
    }
}
```